# red5 doesn't stop in eclipse

Tags: red5, java-server

I can't stop red5 server (0.9.1) in Eclipse.
It throws an error:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: red5
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:357)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:267)
    at org.red5.server.Shutdown.main(Shutdown.java:85)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: red5
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:116)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:203)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1924)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1891)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:274)
    ... 2 more
```

After that I try to run in Debug, but i see error Port is busy.
And I have to restart my PC to make it work again...

I use: Windows 7 64-bit, Java 32-bt, Eclipce Galileo.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you click on the red rectangle on the top right of the console. Instead, go to Servers and Stop it.

Use TCP View (http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) when this happens. You have find port 5080 (red5 default port), right click and End Process. I think it is very useful

A bit late response but I hope this helps for anyone else!

Comment: Thanks for the response.
That time I finished with using 32-bit Windows 7. Couldn't make it work in 64-bit system.
Hopefully I haven't used Red5 since that time.